# Services calling again and again

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

i am having a very simple problem. I have created an activity in which i have called a service in the oncreate method. every time i change the orientation of the device, my service gets called again. Seems like it kills the activity and a new activity is created everytime.

Please help me on how will i prevent my activity to get killed and recreated. That will be helpful in all my applications.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following code in ur `AndroidManifest.xml` in ur `activity` element

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```

this will not recreate ur `activity`

Answer (score 1):

Guess you need to understand this first http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

Handle on Configuration change urself

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior, if you dont want this you better save your data into the

```
Bundle savedInstanceState;
```

You can do this in the onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}
```

When the state returns you can call onResume and restore your data

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
```